# C- undefined reference to <function name>

Tags: c

im new in C programing and im trying for hours to fix " undefined reference to  " error.

i need to code Battleship game and now im only trying to print the game map  on the screen, my code probebly wont make sens to you but im just in the beginning and trying to fix this error.

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*functions declaration*/
void mapmaker(char map[8][8]);
void printmap(char map[8][8]);

int main()
{
char map[8][8];

mapmaker(map);
printmap(map);

}



void mapmaker(char map[8][8])
{
int i,z;
/*creating map*/
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    for(z=0;z<8;z++)
    {
        map[i][z]='~';
    }

}



void printmap(char map[8][8])
{
    int num[8]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int i,z;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d",num[i]);

    printf("\n--------------------------------\n");

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d|",num[i]);
        for(z=0;z<8;z++)
            printf("%c ",map[i][z]);
        printf("\n");
}

}
```

the error occur when the it tries to run the function -> "printmap(map)"
then im getting "undefined reference to "printmap(map)"" error.

thanks alot!

Comment: In `mapmaker`, you forgot a closing bracket. Everything after that is still part of the function's body -- and your compiler should be screaming at you.

Comment: The closing bracket is at the wrong place. If you use GCC, there's an extension called "nested function" that allows the code to compile but the scope nested function won't allow it to be called outside the container function.

Comment: You have to learn to debug. Start by reducing your code down to a minimal example -- for example, remove the mapmaker function and the call to it, and remove any code in the body of printmap. Then add stuff back until you find a small change that causes the problem.

Comment: i cant believe i spend so much time on this stupid thing... thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing the bracket properly of function printmap, Putting an extra bracket in last. and also in mapmaker you did not put the ending bracket of mapmaker function.
This will solve your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*functions declaration*/
void mapmaker(char map[8][8]);
void printmap(char map[8][8]);

int main()
{
char map[8][8];

mapmaker(map);
printmap(map);
return 0;
}
void mapmaker(char map[8][8])
{
int i,z;
/*creating map*/
for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    for(z=0;z<8;z++)
    {
        map[i][z]='~';
    }
  }
} //this was missing
void printmap(char map[8][8])
{
    int num[8]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int i,z;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d",num[i]);

    printf("\n--------------------------------\n");

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d|",num[i]);
        for(z=0;z<8;z++)
            printf("%c ",map[i][z]); //in for loop
        printf("\n"); //not in for loop
} 

// } //this was extra
```

Comment: Please give a little explanation along with the codes, that what and where was the problem and what you did to resolve the error.

Comment: and just like the OP, you too had to post code with improper indentation as an answer...

Answer (score -3):

your `map[i][z]` is not initialized in `printmap(char map[8][8])` Send a reference instead.

Comment: That does not cause a *undefined reference* linker error

Comment: That's not a problem whatsoever, in fact.